# grant access to azure devops git repo to users from another tenant

Tags: git, azure

I am currently using Azure Git repo. It contains repos, which were created and maintained in my teams tenant. I was wondering if it is possible to access my repo from another tenant ?

in other words - how to share same azure git between users in different tenant.

I tried to add guest user but I don't understand how to give him access to the git. (I want to let him to clone and push)

I'm new to azure so I would appreciate a detailed answer.

thank you for giving your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the user to your DevOps organization by their email address and grant them permissions into the repo just like any user associated with your tenant.  Here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-users-to-your-organization) with instructions on adding a user to your organization.  It's a straightforward process.